# Regex - negation of \ in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

When I try: `"(?<=[^\\])(?=\\{\\$)|(?<=\\$\\})"` as a pattern,

it just doesn't like the part: `[^\\]`

For example, I am trying to split:

`"Example \{$TagExampleOne$} {$TagExampleTwo$}"`

Into:

`"Example \{$TagExampleOne$} "` and
`"{$TagExampleTwo$}"`

Is there a way to negate `\` like that?

Edit: Fixed.

Comment: What do you mean by "it just doesn't like the part"?  Are you getting an exception, or the wrong answer, or a message on your screen that says "I don't like this"?  Please provide some details.

Comment: Not sure what would be wrong with your current regex, but it might be worth trying to use the negative lookbehind `(?<!\\\\)` in place of `(?<=[^\\\\])`.

Comment: @ajb Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 26
(?<=[^\])(?=\{\$)|(?<=\$\})

Comment: You have a problem at `(?=\\\\{`.  The string value looks like `(?=\\{` at that point.  The \\ means to match a literal backslash.  However, `{` is expected to be the start of a repetition count (such as `"a{2,3}"`), and the pattern compiler complains because this isn't valid.  If you want to match literal `{`, you need to add _another_ \\ before the `{`.  However, it's probably still wrong. Do you really want your `{` to be _followed_ by a literal backslash, or were you trying to quote the `$`?  If the latter, you have too many backslashes before the `$`.

Comment: By the way, the term you're looking for is "escaping", not "negation".

Comment: My post was edited and all backslashes were redoubled, basically what I ment was only one backslash where there are two.

Comment: You're right, someone was too aggressive in editing.  Could you please describe exactly what you want the `?=` and `?<=` to look for, probably using English words like "backslash", "left brace", etc., so that we can help figure out just what the regex should look like.

Comment: @ajb Check the Exception I quoted, that's the original pattern. Example has only one backslash before "{".

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your original code looked something like

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?<=[^\\])(?=\\{\\$)|(?<=\\$\\})");
```

the exception is caused by the character class `[^\\]`.  Java requires you to double backslashes in a string literal, so that part of the pattern actually looks like

```
(?<=[^\])
```

However, in a character class, when you put a backslash before a `]` (or any other character), it means to interpret that character literally.  So you're telling it to look for a character that isn't a `]`.  Then, since that doesn't close the class, you're also telling it to look for a character that isn't `)`, `(`, `?`, `=`, etc.  Eventually this causes `"Unclosed character class"`.

To put a literal backslash in a character class, you need to quote the backslash with another backslash, which means that in a Java string literal you will need *four* backslashes:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?<=[^\\\\])(?=\\{\\$)|(?<=\\$\\})");
```

This has a `lookbehind` that matches any character that isn't `\`, followed by a lookahead that matches the two characters `{$`; or, alternatively it will match a lookbehind that matches the two characters `$}`.  Hopefully that's what you want.

By the way, Java also has *negative* lookbehind.  If you say

```
"(?<!\\\\).........."
```

it will match any time there is no `\` preceding.  This is different from what you have, because the above will match at the beginning of the string (since there is no preceding `\`), while your regex looks for a *character* that is not `\`, but it needs for there to be at least one character.  I don't know which one you want.